# CatalanNumber[-1] formula on functions.wolfram.com unequals result from Mathematica

Tags: special-functions

The formula for `CatalanNumber[-1]` on [this functions.wolfram.com page](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/CatalanNumber/03/02/0019/) gives:

```
-(1/2)
```

whereas `CatalanNumber[-1]` directly evaluated gives?

```
-1
```

Comment: Mathematica isn't consistent with itself. `(CatalanNumber[n] // FunctionExpand) /. n -> -1` evaluates to `-1/2`. You should report this to [`Wolfram Support`](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Feedback)

Comment: This exact input mentioned in the Possible Issues section here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CatalanNumber.html

Comment: @Chip, didn't think to look at the docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is <del>a bug</del> [an enforced convention](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CatalanNumber.html#253649431) in `CatalanNumber[]` (per Chip). Evaluating

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
PrintDefinitions[CatalanNumber]
```

reveals that the definition `CatalanNumber[-1] := -1` was hard-coded.

Thus, do this for now if you want the gamma function representation's limiting value:

```
FunctionExpand[CatalanNumber[n]] /. n -> -1
   -1/2
```